# jaggery apps not deployed with carbon composite applications project

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js

What I want:
We are looking to use wso2 identity server for our requirement and I wanted to setup the development/build environment for jaggery apps with auto build/ continuous integration features. I just need a way to create and deploy the jaggery app artifact (.zip) file using maven.

What I did: 
I thought that using Composite Application Project I can easily deploy the jaggery artifacts to my carbon server (In this case carbon is).
So I created Composite Application Project and added these jaggery apps to it and changed the serverRole to "IdentityServer" and ran the command "mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true"

Result:
The .car file is generated and deployed to the server successfully but I do not see anything in the folder repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/.

Either I am missing something or there is something wrong with my understanding of jaggery apps deployment. Can someone please suggest me the solution?

Comment: Hello, any help please. We are stuck at this point. :)

Comment: you need to add jaggery zip(not car) into repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps. then it will automatically unzip and deployed.

Comment: Just simply zip the jaggery project and that's all?